# SessionID changes after each request with express server

Tags: javascript, express, session, safari, request

I am currently trying to code a simple login system with express. I have a login page that sends a request to my express server which creates a new session using express-session. After that on my main page a request is send to check the session status of the user. When logging in and immidiately afterwards checking the login status, it incorrectly shows that I'm not logged in. Even the sessionID of the two requests is different. Here is my code:
Server with express:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require("express-session");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const fs = require("fs/promises");
const process = require("process");

const usersFilePath = "./users.json";

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));
app.use(
    session({
        name: "app.sid",
        secret: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {secure: false, sameSite: "none"},
        store: new session.MemoryStore()
    })
)

let users = [];

async function loadUsers() {
    try {
        const data = await fs.readFile(usersFilePath);
        users = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("Found existing user data, loading...");
    } catch (error) {
        users = [];
        console.log("Could not find existing user data")
    }
}

async function saveUsers() {
    await fs.writeFile(usersFilePath, JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
}

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    res.json(users);
});

app.post("/users/register", async (req, res) => {
    const existingUser = users.find((user) => user.name === req.body.name);
    if (existingUser != null) {
        return res.status(400).send("User already exists");
    }

    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
        const user = { name: req.body.name, password: hashedPassword };
        users.push(user);
        await saveUsers();
        res.status(201).send();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send("error LOL");
    }
});

app.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
    const user = users.find((user) => user.name === req.body.name);
    if (user == null) {
        return res.status(400).send("User does not exist");
    }

    try {
        if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
            req.session.user = user;
            console.log("Logged in user: " + req.session.user.name);
            console.log("sessionID: " + req.sessionID);
            res.status(200).json({sessionID: req.sessionID});
        } else {
            res.send("Wrong Password!");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
});

app.post("/users/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("Logout failed");
        } else {
            res.status(200).send("Logout successful");
        }
    })
});

app.get("/users/status", (req, res) => {
    console.log("User: " + req.session.user);
    console.log("sessionID: " + req.sessionID);
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.json({loggedIn: true, username: req.session.user.name});
    } else {
        res.json({loggedIn: false, sessionID: req.sessionID});
        console.log("User not logged in")
    }
})

// Load existing users when the server starts
loadUsers().then(() => {
    const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
    });
});
```

Login script

```
document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/login/', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ name: username, password: password }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("SessionID: " + data.sessionID);

        // setTimeout(() => {
        //     window.open("../index.html", "_self");
        // }, 1);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during login:', error);
    }
});
```

Login status script:

```
async function checkLoginStatus() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/status', {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("SessionID: " + data.sessionID);

      const info = document.getElementById('userInfo');
      const button = document.getElementById('logoutButton');

      if (data.loggedIn) {
        // User is logged in
        info.innerText = `Logged in as ${data.username}`;
        button.style.display = 'Log out';
        button.onclick = "logout()";

      } else {
        // User is not logged in
        info.innerText = 'Not logged in';
        button.innerText = "Log in";
        button.onclick = () => window.open("auth/login.html", "_self");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error checking login status:', error);
    }
  }

  async function logout() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/logout', { method: 'POST' });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // User successfully logged out
        checkLoginStatus(); // Update UI
      } else {
        console.error('Logout failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during logout:', error);
    }
  }

  checkLoginStatus();
```

I have looked far and wide and tried many modifications, but the issue persists. I made sure to use cors with `{credentials: true}` and make the fetch requests with `credentials: "include`.

EDIT: I found out what causes my problem: Safaris IPT (Intelligent Tracking Prevention). When I turned that off it worked perfectly. However, I can't expect every user to turn the setting off before using my site, so how can I prevent the IPT from blocking my request?

Comment: Have you checked the browser *developer* tools to see if the session cookie is being set and sent?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I have, it is being set

Comment: so, what about sent? clearly not

Comment: I am quite new to sending requests and cookies with js, but the network tab shows no request cookies and one response cookie, although different ones between the login and status request. Is this normal?

Comment: are there any warnings in the developer tools console (make sure you show all warnings)

Comment: No there aren't any warnings